# No time travel in case of The Airing of Grievances

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015

We received the hat for `A New Hope` on 17th Dec at this time around `12:30 PM` in India but that's not the case for [`The Airing of Grievances`](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/the-airing-of-grievances) which says post or vote on 23rd of Dec on Meta site.

I have voted on few questions today on Meta StackOverflow but still not received this hat yet.

What is the difference in both hats ?  Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Patience....patience.  The hat will come.  Hopefully.

Comment: even it UTC+14 its not the 23rd yet.

Comment: Just I got [Airing of Grievances](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2451726/arulkumar#winter-bash) hat in India.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the hat is consistent with other time-base hats, it will be eligible to be awarded when it is 12/23 somewhere in the world.  One of the first places to see the new day is the Christmas Islands (UTC +14), and at the current moment, it is 10:54PM.  You need to wait a little more than an hour to find out.

Of course, there is always a chance it is based on another time zone, as such, you have to wait until midnight in that time zone.